# How to change decimal separator of a column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter-table, decimal-point

My problem is that the column storing decimal values saves them as eg. 24.55 instead of 24,55. Having a comma there is how I need the data to be stored.

I'm connecting from a software through PostGIS to my database, but the software is very inflexible in terms of naming columns, size of strings etc... That means I can only change '.' to ',' to make it work. I would appreciate any help.

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4.5.

Comment: What would be desired type with a comma?

Comment: Decimal comma or decimal point is just an input/output issue. They are not stored - as long as your column isn't of character type. That's why I asked about the column data type...

Comment: It's type is double.

Comment: Ohhh, my mistake. I looked at the similar, but wrong column. The one I need to change is smallint. That makes it way easier. Sorry for creating confusion! Should I delete the question?

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 8.4 is long dead and forgotten, you should **really** plan an upgrade to a supported version (at _least_ upgrade to the latest minor version which is 8.4.22 and contains nearly 4 years of bugfixes compared to 8.4.5)

Comment: Thanks, I'll read more on that but I'm not the decision-making here, that's just what our contractor wants us to use so his IT system would work.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use text in your output software, then:

```
replace(your_data::text, '.', ',') as decimal_with_comma
```